# Split string with multiple-character delimiter

Tags: python, string, split

say I have the following string:

```
"Hello there. My name is Fred. I am 25.5 years old."
```

I want to split this into sentences, so that I have the following list:

```
["Hello there", "My name is Fred", "I am 25.5 years old"]
```

As you can see, I want to split the string on all occurrences of the string `". "`, not any occurrence of either `"."` or `" "`.  Python's `str.split()` will not work in this case because it will treat each character of the string as a separate delimiter, rather than the whole string as a multi-character delimiter.  Is there a simple way to solve this problem?

Comment: `split` does not behave like `strip` in that regard.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Works for me

```
>>> "Hello there. My name is Fr.ed. I am 25.5 years old.".split(". ")
['Hello there', 'My name is Fr.ed', 'I am 25.5 years old.']
```

Comment: That's a better solution than using regular expressions!

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> "Hello there. My name is Fred. I am 25.5 years old.".rstrip(".").split(". ")
['Hello there', 'My name is Fred', 'I am 25.5 years old']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use split function in regular expression library :

```
import re
re.split('\. ', "Hello there. My name is Fred. I am 25.5 years old.")
```

Comment: Thanks for the alternative suggestion. This is helpful if I have multiple delimiters. `re.split(r'[\s,.|/]+', 'The.\tbrown fox|jumped,over/the')` returns `['The', 'brown', 'fox', 'jumped', 'over', 'the']`