# Parsing over a text file that has an unusual delimiter using python

Tags: python, parsing, text

In supporting a legacy system, I'm faced with a field data collector that stores data in the following format:

```
# This is a comment <-beacuse it starts at the begining of the file
# This is a comment <- see above
# 1. Item one <- not a comment because it starts with 1.
# Description of Item 1 <- not a comment as it is after a line that starts with a number
data point 1
data point 2
data point etc
3 <-- represents number of data points under Item one

# 2. Item two <-- not a comment
# Description of item 2 <-- not a comment
data point 1
data point ..
data point 100
100
#3. Item three <--- not a comment
# Item three description
0
```

I'm not sure what is the correct way to parse for that file to include each Item as its own list. Note that sometimes but not always the data adds a random space between two different items.

**What is the correct way to parse such a file?**

Answer (score 1):

I would do this in three steps:

1. Remove all comments from the start of the file
2. Split on a regular expression to find all the other comments in the file (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8081663/901059) for an example of how to split using a regular expression)
3. Parse the remaining lines

Answer (score 1):

You could use REGEX and do a [split](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#module-contents) by: `^(?=\# ?\d+\.)`

Explained example here: http://regex101.com/r/gB3xD1